# Why $.removeCookie() dont' work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am trying to make one button with Day/Night mode by using jqueryCookie. I am not sure what is wrong with this code. The first "if" statement would work and add the cookie, but once I refresh the page, body will remove the graybg class anymore while the cookie remains.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var btn = $('#modeSwitch'),
    body = $('body'),
    cookieVal = $.cookie("switchLight");

    btn.click(function(e) {
        if (cookieVal != "2") {
            $.cookie("switchLight", "2", { path: '/' });
            body.addClass('graybg');
            btn.text('Day');
        }else if (cookieVal == "2") {
            btn.text('Day');
            body.addClass('graybg');
            $.removeCookie("switchLight", { path: '/' });
            $(this).text('Night');
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: You said you refreshed the page; if the class is added dynamically, it will disappear on a refresh.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will put the code in function pageLoad() {} and see if that solve the problem.

Comment: I see a possible flaw.... you're only setting cookieVal on document.ready, but never updating it. that means every click that happens on btn will always do the same thing for the given page state until you refresh, at which point it will do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

you may use something like this :

```
$(function(){
var btn = $('#modeSwitch');
var body = $('body');
var cookieVal = $.cookie("switchLight");
    if (cookieVal == "1") {
        body.addClass('graybg');
        btn.val('Night');
    }else{
        body.removeClass('graybg');
        btn.val('Day');
    }
    btn.on('click',function() {
        var cookieVal = $.cookie("switchLight");
        if (cookieVal == "1") {
            $.cookie("switchLight", "0", { path: '/' });
            body.removeClass('graybg');
            $(this).val('Day');
        }else{
            $.cookie("switchLight", "1", { path: '/' });
            $(this).val('Night');
            body.addClass('graybg');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work unless I put them inside an function pageLoad() {} . I like your way avoid using $.removeCookie() tho. very smart move

Comment: One thing I don't understand is why setup var cookieVal again under click function when there is cookieVal set up at beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You should have only a single click handler attached to this button, not two click handlers.  As it stands right now, both click handlers would be invoked.

```
btn.click(function(e) {
    if (cookieVal != "2") {
        $.cookie("switchLight", "2", { path: '/' });
        body.addClass('graybg');
        $(this).text('Day');
    } else if (cookieVal == "2") {
        body.addClass('graybg')
        $.removeCookie("switchLight", { path: '/' });
        $(this).text('Night');
    }; 
});
```

To address your concern about the `graybg` class not being applied on page refresh, that is because you a not assigning that class except in response to a button click event, so you probably need something like this to apply the style on page load.

```
cookieVal = $.cookie("switchLight");
if(cookieVal === '2') {
    btn.addClass('graybg');
}
```

Comment: you guys have quick replies while I was editing my post. So apparently we have almost same code except your extra codes at bottom. thank you, I will give a try